# How To Make Transpose Of Table on PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table with this structure and I need to recreate it as below, searched it before asking here but I couldn't find an answer as I expected. Could anyone help me which query should I use to get expected tables with PostgreSQL. Used `exceljs` npm package, but things become complicated

**Source Table**

| ID | NAME | SLOT | columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD | columnE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | SLOT1 | 300 | 3500 | TRUE | FALSE | 50 |
| 2 | B | SLOT1 | 200 | 2500 | TRUE | TRUE | 100 |
| 2 | B | SLOT2 | 300 | 3500 | FALSE | TRUE | 100 |
| 3 | C | SLOT1 | 300 | 500 | FALSE | FALSE | 150 |
| 2 | B | SLOT3 | 150 | 3500 | TRUE | TRUE | 50 |
| 4 | D | SLOT1 | 150 | 3500 | FALSE | FALSE | 0 |
| 4 | D | SLOT2 | 40 | 200 | TRUE | TRUE | 200 |
| 4 | D | SLOT3 | 150 | 10000 | FALSE | TRUE | 100 |
| 1 | A | SLOT2 | 50 | 450 | FALSE | FALSE | 50 |
| 3 | C | SLOT2 | 80 | 280 | TRUE | TRUE | 100 |

**Expected Results**

Restruct it by `columnA`

| ID | NAME | SLOT1 | SLOT2 | SLOT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 300 | 50 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 200 | 300 | 150 |
| 3 | C | 300 | 80 | NULL |
| 4 | D | 150 | 40 | 150 |

Restruct it by `columnB`

| ID | NAME | SLOT1 | SLOT2 | SLOT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3500 | 450 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 2500 | 3500 | 3500 |
| 3 | C | 500 | 280 | NULL |
| 4 | D | 3500 | 200 | 10000 |

Restruct it by `columnC`

| ID | NAME | SLOT1 | SLOT2 | SLOT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | TRUE | FALSE | NULL |
| 2 | B | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 3 | C | FALSE | TRUE | NULL |
| 4 | D | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

Restruct it by `columnD`

| ID | NAME | SLOT1 | SLOT2 | SLOT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | FALSE | FALSE | NULL |
| 2 | B | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3 | C | FALSE | TRUE | NULL |
| 4 | D | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

Restruct it by `columnE`

| ID | NAME | SLOT1 | SLOT2 | SLOT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 50 | 50 | NULL |
| 2 | B | 100 | 100 | 50 |
| 3 | C | 150 | 100 | NULL |
| 4 | D | 0 | 200 | 100 |

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query ?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis slot names are dynamic

Comment: I guess you will have to build your crosstab SQL dynamically then and use it in EXECUTE using plpgsql.

Comment: Anyway, I have created with `MAX(CASE...WHEN....)`

Comment: Would you self-answer the question? It would be interesting to see what solution did you came up with.

Comment: I'm gonna add when I have free time